# How to close a tkinter window after fixed time automatically?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a GUI which allows user to decide whether to proceed with the script or to terminate it, but if user does not respond in 15 mins I want to kill the window and proceed with rest of the script automatically. I have used root.destroy() in a function but it only executes if there is response from the user.

```
import sys      
import Tkinter   
root = Tkinter.Tk()   
"""def countdown(time):   
    if time==10:   
        root.destroy()   
    else:   
        time +=time """ 
def Yes_callback():    
    root.destroy()   
    return()    
def No_callback():    
    root.destroy() #Kills GUI    
    sys.exit("There is an Overnight execution")#Stops script    
    return() # returns to prog    
ask = Tkinter.Label(text="Do you have any overnight task to run?")    
yes_button = Tkinter.Button(root,text="Yes", command = Yes_callback)    
no_button = Tkinter.Button(root, text="No", command = No_callback)    
ask.pack()   
yes_button.pack()    
no_button.pack()    
#countdown(0)    
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried using countdown function on trial basis but it doesn't work as without user response control doesn't come to countdown function. Is there any way I can accomplish this task?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306222/automatically-close-window-after-a-certain-time

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at after method.

```
widget.after(5000,callback)
```

Ref: [Close a tkinter window after a period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021920/close-a-tkinter-window-after-a-period-of-time)

Comment: Thanks. It worked.